# Is there a Jenkins plugin that visualises SoapUI test results by giving you a graphical report?

Tags: bug-report, jenkins, gui, soapui

I'm basically looking for something like this, but for SoapUI:

[image: cucumber-reporting report for Cucumber test results]

SoapUI displays results in a really nice way in it's GUI. Any chance of getting something similar for/when it runs on Jenkins?

Comment: Cross-posted this to the SoapUI forum: http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=24750

Answer (score 3):

I accomplished a similar thing by running the SoapUI tests within the Maven Build

http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html

one of the outputs is "junitReport : Turns on creation of JUnit-reports, (true/false)" which will then let you use any of of the million JUnit graphing tools.

Hope that helps in finding your solution

Comment: Hey, did you integrate Jenkins with SoapUI Open source?

Comment: Exactly the same process with the two (Pro and OS).  The alternative is to use the testrunner on command line setting the -j https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html

Answer (score 0):

[Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) can help with that.

Quote from plugin page:

> Report formats supported:
>
> > 1. JMeter XML format
> > 2. JUnit format (used by Soapui for example)

I can't tell you more because I'm not using the plugin through SoapUI: I'm using this plugin for JMeter reporting in Jenkins, and it so happens that I've seen that it supports JUnuit format from SoapUI.

Comment: Could you give some more information about how useful you've found the plugin?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I'm using this plugin for JMeter reporting in Jenkins, and it so happens that I've seen that it supports JUnit format from SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you specifics on how to exactly do it, but from what I've read, it is possible.

I checked the soapui.org forums and there is quite a bit of material available. Hope this helps!

http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=24581&p=56413&hilit=integrate+jenkins+with+soap+ui&sid=88893521758c90cf82cb5c13c0274628#p56413

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: let me show you what I have done with my project.
First of all my project is a SoapUI-Maven project, to automatically check a rest web service.
So, in one of my steps tests, I wrote a line in a .csv with the result that I want to measure along time.
With this csv holding the data, just had to set it up in a graphical chart, I have used [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)
To load it in Jenkins , you have to install the 'anything-goes-formatter' plugin, which I think it has some security risks.

Finally got somthing like this:
[image]

Comment: Please avoid link only answers

Comment: Ok, good to know, I just don't wanted to duplicate answers, but i guess you're right

Comment: Duplicating answers on *different sites* is okay. Sometimes even on the same site it's okay.